# Integrating Vert.x with spring data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, dao, vert.x

I am currently using common approach of calling Spring data JPA repository from Spring service class. But as those calls are blocking, performance is not good for my use-case as number of requests I have to handle is very high.

So I plan to use Vert.x. My understanding is that I would need to call DAO repository from verticle, which in turn I need to integrate in service layer.

Would that be correct way of doing that?

Comment: Which won't give you any advantage as it still is blocking. JDBC (and thus JPA) is blocking, no matter how much different stuff you throw at it. So unless you switch to a different data access technology which is non-blocking it won't help. Also you don't need Vert.x you could also use Spring WebFlux for a reactive/non-blocking part but as stated it won't gain you much, simply because of the blocking nature of your data access technology.

Comment: even switching to so called "non blocking DAO" won't help much, as all those JDBC-based frameworks only pretend to be async. What might work somewhat better is mongo

Comment: wow, @injecteer from "all those JDBC based frameworks" jump to mongo? maybe search for non JDBC based framework? Vertx has reactive sql client https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-sql-client